# Fail2Ban, how should the datepattern for this entry look like

Tags: regex, fail2ban, gitlab

I've got following entry in my logfile for gitlab (application.log):

> June 10, 2019 19:04: Failed Login: username=Zzzz ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

How should the datepattern for my Fail2Ban-filter look like? The official documentation is not very helpful.

My regex would look something like this:

```
Failed Login(?:.*)ip=<HOST>$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fail2ban dates are parsed with [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

In fail2ban there is a `datepattern` setting that can be applied filter. `%` need to be doubled up due to the template parsing of the configuration files.

So you have:

```
datepattern = ^%%B %%d, %%Y %H:%%M:
```

The reset of the failpattern assumed this datepattern has been removed. Take note of trailing space, I'm not sure how this is handled.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your datepattern was absolutely correct !